# Print a true IF outcome as formula, not text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple excel formula so when I insert some data on the next available row it prints todays date, or should.

```
=IF($A165<>"", "=TODAY()", "")
```

At present it is literally outputting `=TODAY()`, is there a way to make it output 04/11/2014 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wrapping today in speech marks excel treats this as a string - try this

```
=IF($A165<>"", TODAY(), "")
```

Comment: I will find out tomorrow, but once the statement prints `=TODAY()` , will it remain tomorrow as it prints today?

Comment: `TODAY()` will output `11/4/2014`. If you load the code tomorrow, it will change to `11/5/2014`